# isolating an exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponentiation

It appears it's been a while since I've dealt with advanced algebra (or exponents outside of excel).  I'm writing a tiny piece of software to solve for $n$.  But I can't seem to isolate $n$ in the following equation:

> $$P = L\left(\frac{c(1+c)^n}{(1+c)^n-1}\right)$$

I have gotten just up to:

> $$(1+c)^{n+P} - P = (1+c)^{c+n+L}$$

$P$, $L$, and $c$ are my inputs.

Please advise on how to isolate $n$.

Comment: Is this $$P=L\left(\frac{(1+c)^n}{(1+c)^n-1}\right)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You´ve omitted the factor $c$.

Comment: Yes, it is $$P=L\left(\frac{c(1+c)^n}{(1+c)^n-1}\right)$$

Comment: I apologize for the terrible formatting on my part.  Originally the equation was given to me in the form I supplied...but your form makes more intuitive sense (I've seen it before). Yes it is

Comment: @foo It doesn´t matter. With our experience we know how to interpret such expressions. I´ve made an edit of your post. Please check if you can comprehend the steps of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t get your intermediate result. My calculation is the following.

$P = L\cdot \frac{c(1+c)^n}{(1+c)^n - 1} $

Multiplying the equation by $((1+c)^n - 1)$

$P \cdot ((1+c)^n - 1)= L\cdot c(1+c)^n $

Multiplying out the brackets

$P \cdot (1+c)^n - P = L\cdot c(1+c)^n $

$P \cdot (1+c)^n - L\cdot c(1+c)^n = P $

Factoring out $(1+c)^n $

$(1+c)^n \cdot ( P- L\cdot c)  = P $

$(1+c)^n   = \frac{P}{P- L\cdot c} $

Taking $\ln()$ on both sides.

$\ln\left((1+c)^n \right)=\ln\left(\frac{P}{P- L\cdot c}\right)$

$n\cdot \ln\left(1+c \right)=\ln\left(\frac{P}{P- L\cdot c}\right)$

$n=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{P}{P- L\cdot c}\right)}{\ln\left(1+c \right)}$

Comment: `P⋅(1+c)n−P=L⋅c(1+c)n`  threw me off a little. I have lost my reflex to be able mentally substitute a placeholder like `X` for the right side of the equation to get `P⋅(1+c)n−L⋅c(1+c)n = P`   Also why `ln`? My initial reaction was to use `log`

Comment: I come back in 15 minutes. But to answer the second question. The base of logarithm doesn´t matter.

Comment: @foo Sure you can replace $(1+c)^n$ by $X$ But since you need a general solution you have to re-substiute it at the end. So you don´t really have an advantage by making a substitution.

Comment: @foo $\frac{\log_{10} (a)}{\log_{10}(b)}=\frac{\ln (a)}{\ln(b)}$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{P}{L}(1+c)^n-\frac{P}{L}=c(1+c)^n$$ so
$$(1+c)^n\left(\frac{P}{L}-c\right)=\frac{P}{L}$$
Can you finish now?
It is $$n\ln(1+c)=\ln\left(\frac{P}{P-Lc}\right)$$

Comment: bear with me working on it.  It's amazing that not long ago I was in AP Calc ;(

Comment: I believe so. My own version is rather "clunky" but should suffice:  n=log((P/L)/((P/L) - c))/log(1+c)